# about canvas 3D rotate two style at one time

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, rotation

I want to make a 3d spinning sky,and it rotate 3D canvas by two style.first,rotate around the Z-axis by itself.then,addEventListener,so I can change 3D perspective.Here's what I did:

first,rotate around the Z-axis:

```
for (var i = stars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
stars[i].x = Math.sin(stars[i].timePassed) * stars[i].radius;
stars[i].y = Math.cos(stars[i].timePassed) * stars[i].radius;
stars[i].timePassed+=speed; }
```

then addEventListener,so it can rotate like 3D:

```
var cos = Math.cos(angleY);
var sin = Math.sin(angleY);

for (var i = stars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {    
  var x1 = stars[i].x * cos-stars[i].z*sin;
  var z1 = stars[i].z * cos+stars[i].x*sin;
  stars[i].x = x1;
  stars[i].z = z1;

  var scale=falllength/(falllength+stars[i].z)-0.5;
  ctx.drawImage(canvas2, stars[i].x+w/2, stars[i].y+h/2, 20*scale, 20*scale);}
```

but It's not worke as expected,It can rotate 2 style but not like 3D.The stars like a piece of paper, it is flat and has no thickness.So who can tell me what is the problem?I would be very grateful.thank you.
There's other code here:

```
function innit(){
  for(var i=0;i<maxstar;i++){
  var radiusx=(Math.random()+1)*3*100;//450-900
  var radiusy=(Math.random()+1)*3*50;//210-420
  var b;
  var b = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
  var x1 = radiusy * Math.cos(b);
  var y1 = radiusy * Math.sin(b);
  var z1 = (Math.random()*2-1)*100;
  var t = new star(radiusy , b , x1 , y1 , z1);
  stars.push(t);}}
```

Comment: Well,I know what the problem is.The code about rotate around the Z-axis is wrong,It should be like the addEventListener's code. when I modify the code, new problems have emerged, and I believe that's the main problem:ROTATE AROUND ANY AXIS.Which means when I changed my perspective,the original around the Z axis rotation axis, have become no longer as the Angle of perpendicular to the screen, led to the complete deformation image.  I looked up a lot of formulas, it was complicated.So guys who has a better way?thanks.

Comment: You could pick and chose what you want from [this](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/yzjbret0/). Note: it's far from optimized code but should get you around (pun).